# jQuery .val() not updating on submit

Tags: jquery, webforms

I have the following values from a form being accessed by jQuery using .val():

```
var un0 = $("input.e0").val();
var un1 = $("input.e1").val();
var un2 = $("input.e2").val();
var un3 = $("textarea.e3").val();
```

The original values in those from elements have been added earlier on by a different script that loops the values from AJAX XML data.

The trouble is that when I edit the values in the form (i.e. overwrite them) and submit the form to update my db, the *original values*, rather than the *updated values* are sent. It's as if the new values are being ignored by .val(). If I test what is being posted from the form with an alert(un0); the newly edited value is not retrieved and I can see that the original is being used.

Note. This isn't the case for the textarea (un3) which is working correctly, and updates with a new value on edit.

Any ideas why jQuery isn't using the new .val() of the inputs?

Edited with more source:

Values are set in a previous code block after an XML call from the db. This is executed when an item is clicked.

```
// Construct the output info (for both read and write)
    for (var i = 0; i < field_count; i++){
        data = eval("r" + i);
        $(".r"+i).replaceWith("<span class=\"r" + i + "\">" + data + "</span>");
        $(".e"+i).attr("value", data);
}
```

Then the read-only version is displayed. This had a link that toggles the read-only version off and the form with the same values in it on.

Then on submit jQuery calls the overwrite function:

```
$(".overwrite").click(function() {

// Other conditionals, then ...

if (category=="3"){
    // phone
    var un0 = $("input.e0").attr('value');
    var un1 = $("input.e1").attr('value');
    var un2 = $("input.e2").attr('value');
    var un3 = $("textarea.e3").val();

    // Encode each using myKey
    e0 = Passpack.encode("AES",un0,myKey);
    e1 = Passpack.encode("AES",un1,myKey);
    e2 = Passpack.encode("AES",un2,myKey);
    e3 = Passpack.encode("AES",un3,myKey);

    queryString = 'user_id=' + user + '&cat_name=' + cat_name + '&id=' + item_no + '&v1='+ e0 + '&v2=' + e1 + '&v3=' + e2 + '&v4=' + e3;

}

// Other conditionals, then …

// Call edit.php to make update on db
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "app/edit.php",
    data: queryString,
    success: function() {       
        $("#edit_" + cat_name).hide();
        $("#delete_success").hide();
        $("#right_read").show();
        $("#write_success").show();
        $("#read_" + cat_name).show();
        get_list(0,category);
        read_db(category,item_no);
    }
    });
    time_out();
    return false;
});
```

The values in the form, after editing aren't updated and the submission uses the original values set by the code above.

Comment: at what point is the code you've pasted being executed?

Comment: Are you sure you are updating the variables? It will be good if you posted the full source you are using.

Comment: The variables, e0, e1 etc. are first set buy a different code block. (Read-only values are set too, using r0, r1 etc.) 

Then a script toggles off read-only version of the data to the form which has these values in fields. (jQuery hides one and shows the other.)

Then the form can be updated by overtyping.

There's an update link that runs a function to update the values and submit a PHP script to update the DB (also AJAX). The code above is part of that function, which is called when the update link is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You can do sth like this to get the values AFTER you click the button:

```
$('submit').click(function() {
   var un0 = $("input.e0").val();
   var un1 = $("input.e1").val();
   var un2 = $("input.e2").val();
   var un3 = $("textarea.e3").val();
});
```

Comment: It is done after the submit (in my case 'overwrite') button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Open firebug addon in firefox, and inspect the AJAX request that is being sent. Is it actually passing the same variables at both requests? Place an `alert('something unique')` after *every place* where you assign something to the `queryString` variable, and then `alert(queryString)` just before the AJAX post.

You're either not hitting your condition, or something else is overwriting it. `$.ajax()` isn't broken =)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Firebug is the way alright. (I'm not sure how any site with asynchronous calls could be built without it).

I have gone through a relatively comprehensive debugging process before I asked my question here. All $.AJAX, and $.post() calls I have are working fine as far as I can tell. All calls return the correct XML and all posts return no SQL errors and are posting the correct data (I've already debugged those!) In fact all server side stuff seems to be ok...

Comment: ... I have an alert(un0 + "\n" + e0); which confirms that the data being appended to queryString is working. It's just that the overwritten data isn't being reset. Only the pre-populated data is being used and .val() or .attr('value') won't update it the way I have it.

I am in fact switching higher up between categories, and the default category is working correctly (using these values and .val()). So, my current conclusion is that I have some nasty duplication causing problems somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

hey, i maybe late to the party, but i was working on this same issue, and here is the js code that worked for me:

```
$('.matcher').each(function(){
   var idt = $(this).attr('rel');
   $(this).click(function(){
     var baseval=$('#base_'+idt).attr('value');
     $.post("t_softmatch_p.php",
     { base: baseval, 
      iding: idt
     });
     //alert(baseval + idt);
     $(this).hide();
   })//end click        
   });//end each
```

and here is the HTML form i have, dumping in content from a DB in a loop,

```
echo "<form name=\"f_$iding\" id=\"f_$iding\" action=\"\" method=\"post\">
 ";
echo "".($m+1).") <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"iding\" id=\"iding\" value=\"$iding\">
 ";
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"ing_$iding\" id=\"ing_$iding\" value=\"$ingword\"> ==> 
 ";
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"base_$iding\" id=\"base_$iding\" value=\"$baseword\">  
 ";

echo "<input type=\"button\" name=\"matcher\" id=\"matcher\" class=\"matcher\" title=\"matcher\" value=\"Make match\" rel=\"$iding\">
"; 
echo "</form><br>
";
```